# How to properly add IPv6 data of GeoLite2 into existing table?

Tags: mysql, php

I'm building an application which will use [MaxMind's GeoLite2 City](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) database.

By following a [2016 tutorial](https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-articles/install-maxmind-geoip2/), I imported the data of GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4.csv and GeoLite2-City-Locations-en.csv and also added the helper procedure. Now I can successfully query the location information of IP address which are IPv4.

But I still need to be able to query the location information of IP address which are IPv6. Can I use the same code from the tutorial (shown below) to add the data of IPv6 into the existing table without messing things up? (I will change the file path to GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv6.csv)

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/geoip/GeoLite2-City-CSV_20160503/GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4.csv' INTO TABLE ip_blocks COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES (
@network,
geoname_id,
registered_country_geoname_id,
represented_country_geoname_id,
is_anonymous_proxy,
is_satellite_provider,
postal_code,
latitude,
longitude,
accuracy_radius) SET 
ip_from = INET_ATON(SUBSTRING(@network, 1, LOCATE('/', @network) - 1)),
ip_to = (INET_ATON(SUBSTRING(@network, 1, LOCATE('/', @network) - 1)) + (pow(2, (32-CONVERT(SUBSTRING(@network, LOCATE('/', @network) + 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER)))-1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, **no**, you can't use the exact same code from that tutorial with the IPv6 version.

Here are a few reasons:

1. The `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query that inserts the data uses MySQL's `INET_ATON()` function, which won't work with IPv6. Thankfully MySQL has another function `INET6_ATON()` which supports both IPv4 and IPv6, although it does return a different datatype, `VARBINARY(16)` instead of `integer`. Which brings me to point #2...
2. In the tutorial, the `ip_blocks` table is created with the `ip_from` and `ip_to` columns as `int`, but as mentioned above, you need `VARBINARY(16)` to be compatible with IPv6.
3. The `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query also does some integer math to calculate a min  and max IP address based on the CIDR range in the CSV. This won't work with the binary format returned from the `INET6_ATON()` function.

Most of these obstacles stem from the fact that the IPv6 address space is much larger than the IPv4 space (128 bits versus 32 bits), which means IPv6 can't be stored as a normal integer. So you will need to modify the code and underlying storage quite a bit to make it work.

You can probably use [MaxMind's converter tool](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip2-csv-converter) to get a min and max IP address from the IPv6 range in the CSV, then use the `BETWEEN` keyword to find IP addresses in that range. See this question for background info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414946/check-if-ipv6-is-inside-range

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, I will need to recreate the `ip_blocks` table with the `network_start_ip` and `network_last_ip` columns (instead of `ip_from` and ``ip_to``) being the `VARBINARY(16)` datatype so that I can store the data of IPv4 and IPv6 in this same table. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. You'll have to use the MaxMind tool to convert the CSV format (use the `-include-range` flag to add `network_start_ip` and `network_last_ip` to the output CSV). Then add those 2 columns to your table as `VARBINARY(16)`. Then load the CSV using a similar `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query as the tutorial, but instead of doing the math to calculate min/max IP addresses (for `ip_from` and `ip_to`), you'll take the the `network_start_ip` and `network_start_ip` columns from the CSV and convert them on insert with `INET6_ATON()`. That will make them `VARBINARY(16)`.

Comment: Then you'll need to modify the lookup. The tutorial creates a function called `IP2Location`, which you can modify the select query in that. Or just write your own query. Either way, it'll look like `SELECT geoname_id FROM ip_blocks b
WHERE INET6_ATON('2a01:4ff:ffff:ffff::ffff') BETWEEN b.network_start_ip AND b.network_last_ip`. Also if you run the insert query twice (once for IPv4 and IPv6 since they're separate CSVs), you might be better off creating a separate ID column like `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` to avoid any duplicate key errors on the 2nd run.